# What should the React children type be for components that only accept text and falsy?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What's the type of children so it will allow

```
<MyTextOnlyComponent>
  child
  {" foo "}
  another child
  {false && "should not be shown" }
</MyTextOnlyComponent>
```

I flatten the children to a single string using React.Children.map which strips off falsy values as follows

```
  const content = React.Children.map(
    children,
    (child) => child && `${child}`
  )
    .filter((child) => child)
    .join("");
```

Right now I have the type as `string|string[]` I could put `boolean | undefined | null` as well but it seems too clunky.

Is there an established type that does this.  I just want to ensure there's no other JSX elements.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for. The type for that could look like this:

```
type Falsy = false | 0 | "" | null | undefined;

type TextOnlyChild = Falsy || string;
```

which should accept exactly `Falsy` and `string` type values

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `ReactNode` type:

```
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

You could leverage the [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) type to remove the unwanted types.

```
type ReactTextNode = Exclude(ReactNode, ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal);
```

But as you can see, this is longer than just typing the type yourself.

```
type TextChild = string | boolean | undefined | null;
```